# Never terminating cpu bound c program

Tags: cpu-usage

as you know there are two kind of process, i/o bound and cpu bound...

i need a cpu bound program that never terminates itself...

for example; is it like i wanted?

```
while(1){

    for(int i=0;i<1000; i++);

}
```

Comment: On single core, perhaps. Multicore, definitely not.

Answer (score 3):

`for(;;);` should do it!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *why* do you want a never terminating CPU bound program?

And yes, that would work, but you don't really need the inner for-loop.  The while-loop will run forever on its own (assuming the compiler doesn't optimize it away).

Comment: i will make a kernel module that focus on this never terminating program...

so if i dont put inner loop, shouldnt it be "I/O bound program"???

Comment: That would not be a valid optimization since the control flow would be allowed to exit.

Comment: @tstr: He might be thinking of where a variable reference is used in the while loop clause.  The variable lookup could be optimized out, depending on some form of static analysis.

Comment: No, that wouldn't make it IO-bound since your program is still not doing any IO.  Two levels of loops that do nothing is equivalent to a single loop that does nothing.

Comment: @tster: I swear I've seen compilers optimize out empty loops.  But I think those were all finite loops and I made an inductive leap (sigh).

Answer (score 0):

There aren't only two kinds of processes.  Even if you consider what resource is bounding the performance, there are more than two.  The classic other ones are bandwidth, memory, database connections -- any finite resource or blocking one can be a bottleneck.

But, yes, your process is CPU-bound -- you can see that by looking at your task manager (Windows) or Activity Monitor (Mac) or top (Linux) and seeing it take 100% of your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Those programs probably aren't CPU bound.

I suggest implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes, or something like that.  How about a program that takes a number (say 42), divides it by Pi 1000 times, multiplies it by Pi 1000 times, subtracts the result from the original number, adds it to a variable and increments a counter.  Then repeat that indefinitely.  I suppose you might overflow one of the numeric values, but that should be fixable / preventable.

Comment: You could also make a fork bomb, but while that would use CPU, it might very well cause your computer to crash / become unusable.

Comment: Why do you think his program isn't CPU-bound?

Comment: Running such a program on my machine pushes CPU usage up to 100% (for the core it's running on).  Seems pretty CPU bound to me.